# Using SASS in Vue components the right way

Tags: css, sass, webpack, vue.js

In my Vue component, I changed the language from the default CSS to the explicitly set SCSS, like this.

```
<style lang="scss">
  div.bordy{ border: solid 3px red; }
</style>
```

I also changed the *webpack.config.js* according to [this post by LinusBorg](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/363), so it looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./index.js"],
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: "bundle.js" },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.vue$/, loader: "vue" },
      // { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass' },
      { test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" }
    ]
  },
  babel: {
    presets: ["es2015", "stage-3"],
    plugins: ["transform-runtime"]
  },
  vue: { loaders: [{ scss: "style!css!sass" }] },
  resolve: { alias: { "vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js" } }
}
```

The guy explains that by doing so, we catch SCSS and map it to SASS. However, I'm getting an error saying the following.

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'scss-loader'

I've tried installing the packages as shown below but it gave no difference in the output error.

```
npm install scss-loader --save-dev
```

Here, I get uncertain and googlearching leads me to more confusion because I'm reading hints in all possible directions, not rarely commented with angry shouts of not resolving the issue.

Should I use `style lang="sass"` to being with?

When I try that, I have to install *node-sass* and I'm not sure if I'm resolving the problem or hiding it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) and [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) and it's resolving the problem not hiding it.

`sass-loader` [documentation](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) clearly says:

> The sass-loader requires node-sass and webpack as peerDependency. Thus you are able to specify the required versions accurately.

and here are peerdependency from it's [package.json](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/master/package.json#L29):

```
"peerDependencies": {
   "node-sass": "^3.4.2 || ^4.0.0",
    .....
```

Which means sass-loader will work with these versions of `node-sass`.

It requires it in the very [4th line](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/73cdc388dd5139f1f578d2c0f200bc604071d0c9/index.js#L4) of it's code - **sass-loader/index.js**:

```
'use strict';

var utils = require('loader-utils');
var sass = require('node-sass');
```

Once you have it installed, you can do any of following:

```
<style lang="scss">
or
<style lang="sass">
```

as you are going to use same loader for both of these.